# IOS PDFKit - Annotation content only visible when selected

Tags: swift, xcode, annotations, ios-pdfkit

I would like to fill a form in a PDF file using information users entered into my app. Using PDFKit I am using the following code which is executed after I submit the data in a textfield:

```
for index in 0..<pdfDocument.pageCount{
                if let page = pdfDocument.page(at: index){
                    let annotations = page.annotations
                    for annotation in annotations{
                        if annotation.fieldName == "Candidate name"{
                            annotation.setValue(nameField.text ?? "", forAnnotationKey: .widgetValue)
                            page.removeAnnotation(annotation)
                            page.addAnnotation(annotation)
                        }
```

This code is doing its job, but the content of this annotation is only visible when the annotation is selected in the PDF itself. Otherwise is seems empty.

I read something about the setting 'NeedAppearances', but I can't find it within PDFKit.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the PDF form when filled using iOS, if you have adobe acrobat, change the font size of all form field to a new font size and then try again

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens only in Simulator. Try running it on an actual device and it should work fine.